# How to write type for array of method/function names of object with all items required?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create serializable proxy object for type (for electron ipc), and at runtime I need list of methods. Since TypeScript is transpile/compile time and not runtime - I'm out of luck getting those method names from type.

I want my function for creating proxies to force defining all methods in array as argument. It's kinda ugly approach but I think it will work.

Here is example of such function:

```
type ArrayWithAllMethodNamesRequired<T> = // here is implementation?

function createProxy<TObject>(methods: AllMethodNamesRequiredInArray): TObject { ... }
```